# Я решил работать с MASM на Visual Studio, но код почему-то не компилируется

Tags: visual-studio, ассемблер, masm

Я начал изучать Assembler и решил затронуть Microsoft Macro Assembler x86.
Итак, я запустил VS и настроил его для assembler, после чего попытался писать код (разный, описанный в учебниках), но возникают различные ошибки компиляции.
Однако, я настраивал VS по гайду, и у меня работает следующий код:

```masm
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096

ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.code
SOMETHIN proc

    mov eax,8h
    mov ebx,4h
    add eax,ebx
    invoke ExitProcess,0
SOMETHIN endp
END SOMETHIN
```

Так, что это вообще? Как оно называется?
Просто я даже не понимаю то, в чём пытаюсь разобраться. Код из учебников просто не работает. Видеоматериалов тоже мало.
Какой именно ассемблер - это?
Что вписывать, когда ищу материал по нему?

Comment: Как минимум нужно указать, какие именно ошибки возникают, тогда можно будет что-то подсказать.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовала начать с проекта в VS, в котором используется библиотека Irvine32,
В нем много уже готовых функций. Пользуйся и радуйся.